# What are the parameters on the free seasonal sets?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know you get 2 set pieces in the new season for reaching level 70, what else do you have to do to get the other 4 pieces?

Can you get a free set again if you complete the parameters with a new character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get two more set pieces for completing the Chapter 4 objective "Mercy" (Defeat Zoltan Kulle on Torment II) and two pieces for completing the Chapter 4 objective "Great Expectations" (Complete a Level 20 Greater Rift solo).

Comment: Note: You don't have to get to Chapter 4 in order to get the items, just doing them is enough.

Comment: Note that the seasonal journey achievements are **account wide**, so you can't repeat this for free sets.

Answer (score 2):

As yuuki didn't answer this:

**NO**, you can't get the items on other characters.